# Facebook Javascript SDK post to feed giving "An error occured. Please try later" error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm using the JS SDK to post something on the user's timeline. My website is hosted using site44 and so has a url of the type http://domainname.site44.com. This is the code I'm using:

```
<script>        
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{*********}', // APP ID
      channelURL : 'http://domainname.site44.com/channel.html',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.0'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function share(){
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'something',
        caption: 'something',
        description: (
            'something'
        ),
        link: 'http://domainname.site44.com',
        picture: 'imageLinkInsertedHere'
    });
}
</script>
```

In the channel.html file I have this code:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

and I trigger the share() function when a user clicks on a button using javascript's onclick="share()".

I tested this on fbrell and it works perfectly. However when I use it on my site the pop up gives an error saying `An error occurred. Please try later`. I've gone through other similar questions on Stack Overflow and none of them helped. I also have the correct domain added in my APP settings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the right permissions?

Comment: @WizKid, what do you mean?

Comment: Why are you loading both SDKs? `all.js` and `sdk.js`? just saying

Comment: @AdamAzad, I was loading just the sdk.js at first and it wasn't working. Then I added all.js just to try out everything possible.

Comment: _"Do you have the right permissions?"_, _"@WizKid, what do you mean?"_, you should check your app `Status & Review` tab https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{app_id}/review-status/ and see if the `publish_actions` (`publish_stream`) is approved or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `appId` must not include the curly braces `{`/`}`. Rest of the code seems fine.

But another thing that you should know is that the [**Feed Dialog**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0) **is now deprecated**. You should now use the modern [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) instead. Here's the [**example**](https://www.fbrell.com/Sharing/2%20-%20FB.ui%20Dialogs) for the same.

Comment: Thank you very much. The braces were the problem. I feel like an idiot to have over-looked that.